# AirFlowException - Python_Callable must be callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, airflow, keyword-argument

I made a small change to an existing workflow, and it has broken airflow. Here is the code:

```
dag_name = platform + "_" + report['table']

dag = DAG(
    dag_name,
    catchup=True,
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=report['schedule']
)

with dag:

    trigger_report = PythonOperator(
        task_id=dag.dag_id + '_trigger_report',
        python_callable=trigger_report,
        provide_context=True,
        op_kwargs={
            'report_name': report['report'],
            'amazonmws_conn_id': default_args['amazonmws_conn_id']
        },
        dag=dag
    )
```

Here is the error I'm receiving:

`airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: python_callable param must be callable`

Comment: what's the type of `trigger_report`? could you please print it and show the output? `print(type(trigger_report))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems like you are passing `trigger_report` itself as the `python_callable`.

Is this intentional? does it already have a value?
(probably, otherwise you would've gotten a `NameError: name 'trigger_report' is not defined`)

Comment: trigger_report is a short function that requests a report (via API) and confirms that the request succeeded. I didn't alter trigger report at all (confirmed via history)

Comment: @AshleyO could you please, right before the `PythonOperator` line, print the type of trigger_report? `print(type(trigger_report))` . let's see what the interpreter thinks it is at this moment

Comment: Adam you were correct in checking the type. Due to a previous loop, trigger_report was being redefined as something other than a function. I fixed it and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 15):

For anyone else receiving this, the error is due to the task and the python_callable function having the same name.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What actions would you propose then?

Comment: wrong example: create_host = PythonOperator(task_id="create_host", python_callable=create_host, dag=dag). In right method python_callable=createhost.

Answer (score 1):

The error is obvious, you are putting a PythonOperator inside a variable and calling that variable as a python function inside a PythonOperator!!!!

1- python callable must be a function and not a variable.

2- you shouldnt and cant call same thing inside a function.

3- in your case `trigger_report` is a task and something related to airflow and not python basic things.

**Update for similar errors:**

If you cared to follow the above but the problem was insisting.
You must make a non-callable, callable.

use `functools`

heres an example:

```
import functools

def your_func(value1):
    return ""

trigger_report = PythonOperator(
    task_id="aaaa",
    python_callable=functools.partial(your_func, value1=1),
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error also happens if the function name you pass to `python_callable` has brackets. So, if your function is abc(), you should pass `python_callable=abc`.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes python_callable could be defined as string accidentally.

```
task1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id = 'task',
    python_callable=my_callable_func, # True
    # python_callable="my_callable_func", # False
    dag = dag
)
```